# Trouble creating function. Can someone assist me?

Tags: mysql, function

Can anyone help, my function has an error somewhere, but I can't find it?

A sample output should be like

```
a_testbed.PrevMonth('2012-05-19', 6)
returns '2011-11'
```

I am getting an error:

> 1292 (22007) Truncated date value: '2011-11' for column return_date at
>   row 1:

```
CREATE function prevmonth(in_date DATE, in_mn_count INT) 
returns DATE 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE return_date DATE; 

  IF in_date IS NULL THEN 
    SET return_date= date_format(date_add (curdate(), INTERVAL(in_mn_count-12) month), 'Y-%m'); 
  ELSE 
    SET return_date= date_format(date_add (in_date, INTERVAL (in_mn_count-12) month), '%Y-%m'); 
  END IF; 

  RETURN return_date; 
END; #
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you declared that your function will return a `date`, and `'2011-11'` can not be converted to a `date`.

You should change the second line in your function declaration to `returns varchar`.